# Как правильно выбрать элементы при помощи nth-child?

Tags: html, css, css3

Привет. Не могу разобраться с формулой, необходимой для выборки элементов:

```
1,4,7
2,5,8
3,6,9
```

Пытался делать `1n, 2n и 3n` и `1n+3, 2n+3, 3n+3`, но это не сработало.

Comment: вот неплохой сервис - http://www.topdesignagencies.com/nth-test/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
li {
  color: #000;
}

li:nth-child(3n-2) {
  color: red;
}

li:nth-child(3n-1) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
</ul>
```